# How do i find what is affecting the width of this div? CSS

Tags: css

I am messing with a wordpress theme. I am using firefox and have webdeveloper (and other tools) installed. I am trying to adjust a div width but it is not listening to me. I suspect theres a % used since when i tried setting a max-width to a parent it became MUCH shorter (then the size i specified). The style file is 3k... I tried narrowing it down but its troublesome.

What tools and technique can i use to spot the problem?

Comment: Maybe try firebug instead of webdeveloper, I think it's better.

Comment: Google Chrome's inbuilt debugger/inspector is good, as well.

Comment: @abhinav chrome like firebug on firefox; doesnt show (max-)widths even tho i see #content, set the max width, see the effect yet found no mention

Comment: I'll throw the IE developer tool in the ring for this. You can use the 'trace styles' option to get a list of the CSS styles applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug and inspect the element to see all affecting attributes.

Comment: It doesnt mention widths at all in it. I see #content in it and i set content width (I see it affecting the page) yet it doesnt show up. But i figured out the css problem but i havent figured out how to find the css for these problems